# Postgres - Combine two columns with distinct values and get distinct on the combined values

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, distinct

I have a table called `test_table` that looks like below

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts | timestamp with time zone |  | not null |  |
| ba | integer |  |  |  |
| ca | integer |  |  |  |

Now if I run distinct on column `ba`, I get

| ba |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 11 |

Similarly if I run distinct on column `ca`, I get

| ca |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 18 |
| 20 |

Now I want to combine the values of these two `distinct` columns and get a `distinct` out of the `combined` values such that the output looks like below

**Expected Output**

| combo |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 18 |
| 20 |

I can do a `DISTINCT` on multiple columns like so

```
select distinct ba, ca from test_table;
```

But I can't figure out how do I combine these two columns and get distinct values out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are after a union of these two columns:

```
select ba
from test_table
union
select ca
from test_table;
```

Comment: Just clarifying that "DISTINCT" isn't needed here, because UNION clause eliminates duplicates unlike "UNION ALL".